# Reconnect ethernet link over (Magic) Packet

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, network-adapter, magic-packet

is there a possibility to send a computer, network adapter or any other device a specific packet over the mac or something similar that reconnects the ethernet connection, for example it forces the ethernet adapter to request a new ip over dhcp?

Comment: It may help if you explain not only what you want but also why you want that.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)?

Comment: If you can send it a packet over its Ethernet interface, then its Ethernet must already be connected, at the Ethernet layer. It sounds to me like you to want to fix an IP addressing problem on a machine with a working Ethernet connection. I'd recommend setting up IETF ZeroConf (automatic IPv4 link-local addressing, multicast DNS name resolution, and multicast DNS service discovery) on the machine so that even if it is failing to do DHCP or has an incorrect static IP address, you can still discover and connect to it via ZeroConf.